# What cards are rarer than epic?

Tags: clash-royale

I saw a hint on the loading screen saying that there is a rumor that there exist cards that are rarer than epic cards, or something to that effect. What cards are these, and which arenas can I get them in?

Comment: From what I'm seeing, the only cards that might be considered higher than Epic are like the Princess, Royal Giant, and Ice Wizard, which are available in Arena 7, 7, and 5 respectively, but maybe they plan on releasing more in the future?

Comment: [Royal Giant](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Royal_Giant) is just a common card

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rarity which is above Epic is Legendary. Those cards have a rainbow color and hexagonal shape.

At the moment, there are only 13 of these :

- [Inferno Dragon](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Inferno_Dragon), that you can obtain in the P.E.K.K.A's Playhouse (Arena 4).
- [Lava Hound](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Lava_Hound), that you can obtain in the P.E.K.K.A's Playhouse (Arena 4).
- [Graveyard](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Graveyard), that you can obtain in the Spell Valley (Arena 5).
- [Ice Wizard](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Ice_Wizard), that you can also obtain in the Spell Valley (Arena 5).
- [Miner](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Miner), that you can obtain in Builder's Workshop (Arena 6).
- [Sparky](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Sparky), that you can also obtain in the Builder's Workshop (Arena 6).
- [The Log](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/The_Log), that you can also obtain in the Builder's Workshop (Arena 6).
- [Princess](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Princess), that you can obtain in the Royal Arena (Arena 7).
- [Electro Wizard](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Electro_Wizard), that you can also obtain in the Royal Arena (Arena 7).
- [Lumberjack](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Lumberjack), that you can obtain in the Frozen Peak (Arena 8).
- [Night Witch](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Night_Witch), that you can also obtain in the Frozen Peak (Arena 8).
- [Bandit](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Bandit), that you can obtain in the Jungle Arena (Arena 9).
- [Mega Knight](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Mega_Knight), that you can obtain in the Hog Mountain (Arena 10).

It is also possible to get all of those in [Legendary Chests](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_Chest#Epic_and_Legendary_Chests).

Comment: Also note that Legendary cards have a hexagonal shape.

Comment: There are more than 5 legendaries, you forgot Log, Electro Wiz, Lumberjack, Graveyard, etc. High legendaries can be obtained from any chest, but is a certainty from the legendary chest

Comment: This answer needs to be updated

Comment: Someone please removing 'The upcoming' from the mega Knight after its release.